# Javascript multiple images loader

Tags: javascript, html, image, loader, preload

I want to make a javascript image loader.

This is what I try :

```
function ImgLoader() {

   this.imgs_ = {
       0 : {name: "floor", img: new Image()},
       1 : {name: "highlight", img: new Image()},
       2 : {name: "player-north", img: new Image()},
       3 : {name: "player-south", img: new Image()},
       4 : {name: "player-west", img: new Image()},
       5 : {name: "player-east", img: new Image()},
       6 : {name: "food_small", img: new Image()},
       7 : {name: "food_medium", img: new Image()},
       8 : {name: "food_large", img: new Image()},
   };

}

 ImgLoader.prototype.load = function() {

 for (var i = 0; typeof(this.imgs_[i]) != "undefined"; i++)
     this.imgs_[i].img.src = "img/" + this.imgs_[i].name + ".png";
 }
```

With this method, I have an "array" of my images, and I can work easily later with.
But, it appears that sometimes, few images are not fully loaded.

What is the best way to make this kind of loader ?

Thanks !

---

Okay Šime Vidas said a very good solution ... BUT :
We can not be certain that the image is fully loaded !

This is the code :

```
var imgs = Object.create( null ); // or var imgs = {};

[
   'floor',
   'highlight',
   'player-north',
   'player-south',
   'player-west',
   'player-east',
   'food_small',
   'food_medium',
   'food_large'
].forEach(function ( name ) {
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = 'img/' + name + '.png';
    imgs[ name ] = img;
});
```

Use is :

```
imgs.food_small;
```

But if I check Image complete Property like this

```
console.log(imgs.food_small.complete);
```

Sometimes we can seen : false

I think we should wait for an event like 'onload' before load the next image in the forEach

Comment: are you able to use jQuery for this?

Comment: you mean they are not fully loaded before you add them into the html, or they won't appear at all on the rendered page?

Comment: Also why not make it a real array so that you don't need to check typeof, and you can use the length property eg. 
this.imgs_ = [
               {"name":"floor","img":new Image()},
               {"name":"highlight","img":new Image()}
             ]

Comment: Notice how all those `img: new Image()` parts violate DRY. You don't need to hard-code all those. Instead, you can create new images dynamically (inside a loop).

Comment: I know how to create Image dynamically ;)
Indeed, I use all this image to draw in html canvas.

So, I need to have an "Image object" ...

Comment: @user1499872 My point was that you don't need to hard-code `new Image` for each image. You can just write that expression *once* inside a loop. You would get the same result.

Comment: My first question has been updated :)

Comment: @user1499872 You can (and you should) initialize the image-loading process for all images at once. It would be senseless to wait for one image to fully load, before initializing the load process for the next image. However, it would be useful to be able to delay certain code until *all* images have been fully loaded. You can achieve such functionality via [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). However, since that is a different issue, consider creating a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
var imgs = Object.create( null ); // or var imgs = {};

[
    'floor',
    'highlight',
    'player-north',
    'player-south',
    'player-west',
    'player-east',
    'food_small',
    'food_medium',
    'food_large'
].forEach(function ( name ) {
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = 'img/' + name + '.png';
    imgs[ name ] = img;
});
```

Now you can retrieve each individual image like so:

```
imgs.food_small
```

For instance:

```
ctx.drawImage( imgs.food_small, 0, 0 );
```

Comment: Yes it's a pretty good idea, but how can I retrieve the preloaded food_small image to draw it in my canvas ? (for example)

Comment: Wow ! Very nice :)
Thank you very Much Šime Vidas ! Great Idea !

Just a little question ... What is the difference between new Object(); and Object.create(null); ?

Comment: @user1499872 `Object.create(null)` creates and object that *doesn't* inherit anything. In contrast, normal objects inherit from `Object.prototype`. Since `imgs` is used as a hash, it's best to have it not inherit anything. (Note, though, that `Object.create` and `.forEach` aren't implemented in IE8, so you would have to provide ES5-shim).

Answer (score 0):

First, insert this function as is

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
            $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
                $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
            });
        }
```

To Use it, insert all images into the below function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    preload([
        '/images/image1.png',
        '/images/image2.png'
    ]); 
});
```